# AXS Tokens missing

Tags: tokens

I have a problem tracking down what happened to some AXS tokens.  When looking at transfers for the address, you can see 4 deposits : https://etherscan.io/token/0xf5d669627376ebd411e34b98f19c868c8aba5ada?a=0x3432F2E175B57c904058A90528201280414eCce7

When I go to the `Contract` tab and call the `balanceOf` function, it says the balance for the same address as above (0x3432F2E175B57c904058A90528201280414eCce7) the balance is 0.

I found 2 swaps, but they don't account for the full amount :

- https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf599749c27da06a601aeec100a84f88d82b60546e57691a66617c421332c1806
- https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf2313ea061f9d8392dd0b3cf31b03e3ace0df95874587ab89dfe5735ee5c4824

Is there a (easy) way to find out what happened to these missing coins?